# What sort of feeding schedule should I use for pepper plants?

Tags: vegetables, peppers, fertilizer

I've been trying to find out about feeding my peppers plants. So far the information I've found is very inconsistent, so I'd like something as definitive as possible.

When should I start feeding my pepper plants?

And from then, how frequently should I feed them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Technically you only need to feed them when the soil is deficient of one or more nutrients. This is probably why you see such a range of advice - people grow them in a range of conditions, composts, etc. For example a pot or re-used compost is more likely to become deficient of nutrients.

Personally I usually only feed them once - usually a few weeks after the seedlings (or store bought plants) have been potted on to their final location. This gives them time to get established. I use a general purpose liquid fertilizer feed. My conditions are: raised beds built up with soil and compost (and annually fortified with new compost),  plus pots with mixed store-bought compost.

The only other time I've used a feed was a few years ago when I had some trouble with seedlings getting started. Thinking it was an extreme nutrient deficiency essential at germination, I used the feed as soon as the seedlings appeared. With hindsight I suspect I was seeing damping-off.